# display product label on "out of stock " products in magento site

Tags: image, magento, magento-1.9

We are using magento 1.9.0 version.

We wants to display the product label as `out of stock` on those products which are set as out of stock in admin panel.

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the "out of stock" label on product view page, write the below code in the file `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php    
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
    $qty = $stock->getQty();
    if($qty <= 0)
    {
?>
    <span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
<?php
    }
?>
```

And if you want the label on the category page, write in `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

**NOTE** : It is assumed that you are using magento-1.9 or greater